# Get all different values with a certain key in list of dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a list of Dictionaries.

```
List<Dictionary<String, String>> data = GetData();
```

The dictionaries contain a key named "Month" with values like "1/2010" etc. I need a list of strings with all different months that appear in the Dictionary-list.

Comment: Different months - uniquue months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple with LINQ:

```
var months = data.Select(dict => dict["Month"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or if not all of the dictionaries had the entry:

```
var months = data.Select(dict => {
                            string value;
                            bool hasValue = dict.TryGetValue("Month", out value);
                            return new { value, hasValue };
                         })
                 .Where(p => p.hasValue)
                 .Select(p => p.value)
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

EDIT: My original version didn't include the `Distinct` call, so it would have included duplicates. It now won't.

Comment: Does it select all months? Looks like some kind of Distinct/GroupBy should be here for different/uniquue months?

Comment: @Davide: Not now I've added Distinct calls :)

Comment: Yes, I realized that ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want a one-liner (yields distinct values, and still works if not all dictionaries have the entry)

```
var result=data.SelectMany(x => x)
   .ToLookup(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value)["Month"].Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use LINQ:

```
List<string> months = new List<string>();
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> aDict in data)
{
    string aMonth;
    if (aDict.TryGetValue("Month", out aMonth))
        months.Add(aMonth);
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't want duplicates:

```
List<string> months = new List<string>();
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> aDict in data)
{
    string aMonth;
    if (aDict.TryGetValue("Month", out aMonth) && !months.Contains(aMonth))
        months.Add(aMonth);
}
```

Comment: You could use a HashSet for better performance for removing duplicates then copy the result into a List for output

Comment: You're right. It just depends on what he wants to obtain. Is the order important? Furthermore, the insertion performance for the HashSet is worse that the one for a simple List, so I don' t know if it's worth the pain, it obviously depends on the numbers.

Comment: Insertion for a HashSet is only slightly worse than insertion into a List, but the lookup for "obtains" in hashmap is O(1) while O(n) for list.